# JavaFX: Any way to add tooltips to ChoiceBox items

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tooltip

I'm trying to add `Tooltips` to every item of a `ChoiceBox` but I can't find a proper way to do that. It seems like you have to get the items by `getSelectionModel()` and add a `Listener` because the `Tooltip` class won't work on that but I only was able to add a `ChangeListener` that didn't fit the task and a `EventListener<MouseEvent>` seems not to work with that. Has anyone a idea how to do that or a way I could try because I'm new to JavaFX and maybe it's quite simple. Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting to have tooltips displayed on each element when the `ChoiceBox`'s popup is showing? If so, I don't think you can do that with a `ChoiceBox` (though you can with a `ComboBox` by using its `cellFactory`). If you just want a tooltip on the base control which depends on the selected item, you can observe the `selectedItem` in the selection model as you describe.

Comment: @James_D I was afraid that that would be the answer I get.  But thanks for enlighten me. I will think about replacing the ChoiceBox with a ComboBox.

Comment: There is almost no difference between the functionality of a `ChoiceBox` and the functionality of a (non-editable) `ComboBox`